# $s$-parameterized operator-valued Dirac delta function

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, quantum-optics

So I am reading the book named 'Quantum Optics An Introduction' by Werner Vogel, Dirk-Gunnar Welsch, Sascha Wallentowitz and in the section 'Phase-space representations', I struggle to follow one step in their derivation of the s-parameterized operator-valued Dirac $ \delta $ function. It reads as follow:

$$\hat{\delta}(\hat{a}-\alpha;s) = \frac{2}{\pi(1-s)}:\exp[-\frac{2\hat{n}(\alpha)}{1-s}]:$$

Then it says this can be further evaluated to this:

$$\hat{\delta}(\hat{a}-\alpha;s) = \frac{2}{\pi(1-s)}:\exp[\frac{s+1}{s-1}\hat{n}(\alpha)]\exp[-\hat{n}(\alpha)]:$$

This is where I struggle to follow.
If anyone can explain how to get from the first line to the second line, it will be very helpful.

Comment: Isn't it just $\frac{s+1}{s-1}-1 = -\frac{2}{1-s}$?

Answer (score 4):

I don't know about the details of the operator $\hat{n}(\alpha)$, but it seems like a standard application of the BCH formula
$$[X,Y] = 0
\;
\Rightarrow
\;
\exp(X)\exp(Y) = \exp(X+Y)$$
with
$$X = \frac{s+1}{s-1}\hat{n}(\alpha),
\quad
Y = -\hat{n}(\alpha).
$$
We're only using the fact that $\hat{n}(\alpha)$ commutes with itself; the normal ordering is not important for this argument.

Comment: That's what I thought initially but the $\hat{n}(\alpha)$ is multiply by 2 in the first line while applying the BCH formula in the second line give me a $s$ in the front

Comment: Open Mathematica and type $\text{Factor[}(s+1)/(s-1)-1\text{]}$.

Comment: LOL
I feel so stupid
Thanks man

Comment: You should probably accept the answer, such that nobody else spends more time looking at it.

Comment: @HansMoleman: Perhaps you can just add in your answer that the BCH formula has the form it has because $\hat{n}(\alpha$ commutes with itself.